# myOra SQL Fetching table

Tags: mysql, oracle, create-table

User Table

```
 userid   Name        

    1        Test1          

    2        Test2        

    3        Test3          

    4        Test4
```

Book Table

```
    userid   Destination       

    1        US

    2        UK

    1        MEXICO

    1        INDIA

    3        CANADA

    1        CHINA

    4        CANADA

    1        CHINA
```

based on the table above, what method should i use to show this result when inserting the query

here is the result that i wanted

```
 bookCount   userid

    5        1          

    2        2        

    1        3          

    1        4
```

Comment: what's your attempt so far? Also,   mysql <> oracle, tag the rdbms correctly

Comment: Hello, i have added and more clearer question that i need help on. i do have some attempt , but most of them ended up SQL command wrong

Comment: How are you counting?

Comment: SELECT userid, COUNT(userid) AS count 
FROM book 
GROUP BY userid 
INNER JOIN user ON userid=userid
having COUNT(userid) >1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) bookCount, userid
FROM Book
GROUP BY userid;
```

See [MySQL GROUP BY](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) for insight. You don't need to use a join:

```
SELECT book.userid, COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM book INNER JOIN `user` ON book.userid=`user`.userid 
GROUP BY book.userid
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the help ! apprciate it. but i have some question and i have added to my main thread,  could you guide me a way on it ? thanks

Comment: hello, no, the bookcount is after count , i need is that from book table use COUNT to count how many booking there is for each userid

Comment: i have added my code (which is failed) to the comment.

Comment: You don't need to join the tables to fetch the expected data.